# Getting gl_Position value with getBufferSubData

Tags: javascript, webgl

Is there a way to get `gl_Position` value or the value of a `varying` variable with `getBufferSubData` (or something similar) after `drawArrays`?

Comment: Please tell why close vote and -1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With WebGL1 there's no generic way to get the output of a vertex shader, however with **WebGL2** you can use [transform feedback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLTransformFeedback).